# Downgrade macOS Sierra of a brand new MacBook

Tags: macos, ssd

Here is my story.
Few weeks ago I've bought a brand new MacBook Pro 13' (2015 edition). I've opened it and installed macOS Sierra for the first time. This laptop has never been on some other OS. However, I experience some UI lags which are just killing me and my experience. I've never expected this from a new MacBook Pro. For example when I scroll through Facebook or trying to resize some application (even if I try to resize the activity monitor) there is a noticeable lag and 'decrease of the FPS'. Not really expected this kind of issues.

Just for my peace of mind, I've run a few benchmarks (CPU, GPU, SSD), downloaded a few 'normal-weight' games and everything looks OK. Games have I would say normal FPS and when I compare the benchmarks results they are pretty good and almost the same compared to other 2015 MacBook Pro's.

I was told that this UI lag is because of the OS and if I downgrade and wait until the next macOS release, this will be probably fixed. So, OK I want to downgrade, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: I find it hard to believe the lag is caused by the OS.  I'm running Sierra on a 2015 MBP and it runs fine for me.  How much RAM do you have?  How full is the drive?

Comment: Where does it say that the lag is due to the OS?

Comment: @fsb who told the OP I was after a citation that we could investigate - if just a random person then we can't do anything

Comment: I was trying to ask in a nice way without saying we don't believe that the OS caused the lag - ie criticise the issue not the person saying it

Comment: It's a base model 2015. My friend told me that he experienced the same upgrading to Sierra. So what can cause the lag in case I've checked the components? 8gigs of ram / 128 ssd (80 free) / intel i5 iris 6100

Answer (score 2):

Macbook Pro 2015 came with El Captain version pre-installed in factory therefor you can easily revert back to Factory installed OS by using Internet Recovery.
Don't forget to Backup everything. (since it is a new Macbook pro, maybe you don't have much in it yet to backup? otherwise backup everything. Use TimeMachine to backup)

Now, turn off your Macbook. Turn it on and hold Command+Option+R
You will see a rotating earth icon. Connect to your WiFi and let it download and install El Captain from Apple servers.

Comment: That's not exactly true. There is no other option than Sierra even in the internet recovery mode.

Comment: You'll need to format your entire hard disk using disk utility in internet recovery mode first. Doing this, you can revert back. Even if you reinstall Sierra, you'll have a fresh version without any of mentioned issues. I'm using same macbook pro i5 2015 and I'm not experiencing lags as how you described. Also reverted back to el captain using internet recovery just last week while trying to solve some issues